# How to override register controller (step by step registration) using Symfony2.8 PGUX_multiUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, overriding, fosuserbundle

I'm currently developping the user part of a web application (registration). I have 2 different types of users (buyers and sellers), I added the [FOSUserBundle](http://knpbundles.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) to my project, and [PUGXMultiUserBundle](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) in order to have an easy user management.

I can display my form and add easily add some fields to my forms but I don't know how to override the controler to handle the registration and move to step 2 (which is used to add the shop informations).

My current `RegistrationSellerController` is working fine to display the form and register a seller. I just need to override it to manage the redirections.

```
<?php
namespace UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class RegistrationSellerController extends Controller
{
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
         $registration_manager = $this->container->get('pugx_multi_user.registration_manager');
         return $registration_manager->register('UserBundle\Entity\Seller');
    }
}
```

Where can I get the form value as in [SF2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html) and manage different redirections regarding of the result of the registration (same page if there is some errors, and step2 if the user is well registrated) ?

Comment: You need to override the controller which is handling the Registration Process (I presume it's fos user bundle doing this) You should find the code to do this here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html

Comment: PGUXmultiUserBundler is overriding the FOSUBundle registrationController and the function register(); of the $registration_manager is actualy doing the registration of my user. It is working fine but I don't know how to override the function to manage my step by step process...

Comment: Can you not use the get parent mentor in your bundle class to override pguxmultiuserbundle registration action? Then create the same controller and extend it. That way you can overwrite the method.